no able to open .xlsx file using openpyxl in VS code . Gives error as shown
PS C:\Users\Asit\Desktop\python> python -u "c:\Users\Asit\Desktop\python\excel_project\excel.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Asit\Desktop\python\excel_project\excel.py", line 3, in <module>
    wb = xl.load_workbook('transactions.xlsx')
  File "C:\Users\Asit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 346, in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
                         data_only, keep_links, rich_text)
  File "C:\Users\Asit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 123, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Asit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 95, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
  File "C:\Users\Asit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\zipfile\__init__.py", line 1362, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
              ~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'transactions.xlsx'

Inspite of being in the same folder its showing file not found error
I tried using absolute path and putting the in different folders. Its not working.

Your current working directory appears to be C:\Users\Asit\Desktop\python and you're running a python script in c:\Users\Asit\Desktop\python\excel_project , so there are two directories in use. You state Inspite of being in the same folder which same folder? If the file cannot be found it's because it's not in the directory you're trying to find it in.

Looks like you're trying to open transactions.xlsx relative to your current working directory. Please show the code you're using when specifying an absolute pathname
